# running java applications with/without an os on BeagleBoard

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded, beagleboard

I am taking on a project with the BeagleBoard XM. I have no experience with embedded systems. For that matter, I don't have any experience with operating systems. I do have experience with Java and Eclipse, which is why I was wondering of there were ways to write a Java application in Eclipse on my desktop and run it on the BeagleBoard without an OS (e.g Angstrom). Is it possible to get the BeagleBoard to run this program without user input? Maybe I could compile it then load it to the BeagleBoard?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Eclipse to run non-Java application to run it on the beagleboard without an OS.

Comment: Java needs an OS.  For BeagleBoard, that OS will likely be Linux.  The Linux you'll install on your BeagleBoard won't be a full-fledged desktop with an Ubuntu Unity UI like you might install on a laptop or PC, but it'll still be Linux.  Angstrom is a version of Linux.  You need to decide if you want to run Java on top of that, or if you might prefer your UI to be in C/C++.  Or GTK+/Python.  Or something else altogether.  You can do much with "remote debugging" from Eclipse, but at the end of the day your BeagleBoard *will* be running an OS.